# How can I compute this sum of binomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, binomial-coefficients, closed-form

Is there any way to compute the following sum:
$\displaystyle{
\sum_{\ell = {n + 1 \over{\vphantom{\LARGE A}2}}}^{n}{n \choose \ell}5^{n - \ell}}$ where $n$ is odd.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Hint : try to see the connection with newton's binomium theorem.

How do we rewrite $5^{n+1}$ with the binomial coëfficiënts ?

Use the symmetry of the binomial coefficients.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Without $5^{n-l}$ it gets $2^{n-1}$. My intuition is that we can get something like $6^{something}$, do you agree?

Comment: @user109537 yes something like that. Welcome to MSE :)

Comment: Ok, thanks. Any idea how to go on? I made a lot of tests but no one gave me good results?

Answer (score 0):

Hints : What can you say about the connection $\displaystyle{
{n \choose \ell}}$ with $\displaystyle{
{\ell-n \choose \ell}}$ ?

Look at $a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2+...a_n x^n$

What happens if you multiply that with $(x^n+1)$ ?

Comment: Did you read this ?